# Click on an image in gridview and view it in full screen

Tags: java, android, gridview, uri

As said in the title i want to click on the images displayed at my gridview (which is polulated by selecting images from the device) and view the image in full screen. code for the gallery is

```
public class Gallery extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn, Back;
    int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1;
    String imageEncoded;
    List<String> imagesEncodedList;
    private GridView gvGallery;
    private GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter;
    protected static ArrayList<Uri> ImagePaths = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mSelected = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String TAG = "Gallery";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        Back = findViewById(R.id.svb);

        gvGallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);



        for (int y = 0; y < ImagePaths.size(); y++) {
            galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ImagePaths);
            gvGallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
            gvGallery.setVerticalSpacing(gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing());
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) gvGallery
                    .getLayoutParams();
            mlp.setMargins(0, gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing(), 0, 0);
        }

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
            }
        });
        Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Gallery.this, NewNoteActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data
                Uri mImageUri;
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (data.getData() != null) {

                    mImageUri = data.getData();

                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();


                    ImagePaths.add(mImageUri);
                    galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ImagePaths);
                    gvGallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
                    gvGallery.setVerticalSpacing(gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing());
                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) gvGallery
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    mlp.setMargins(0, gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing(), 0, 0);

                } else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();
                            mArrayUri.add(uri);

                            // Get the cursor
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            // Move to first row
                            cursor.moveToFirst();

                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                            imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                            cursor.close();


                        }
                        for (int y = 0; y < mArrayUri.size(); y++) {
                            ImagePaths.add(mArrayUri.get(y));
                            galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ImagePaths);
                            gvGallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
                            gvGallery.setVerticalSpacing(gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing());
                            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) gvGallery
                                    .getLayoutParams();
                            mlp.setMargins(0, gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing(), 0, 0);
                        }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

}
```

and the code for the adapter which puts the selected images on the grid view is the following

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    private int pos;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageView ivGallery;
    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri;
    public GalleryAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri) {

        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.mArrayUri = mArrayUri;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mArrayUri.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mArrayUri.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        pos = position;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gv_item, parent, false);

        ivGallery = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivGallery);

        ivGallery.setImageURI(mArrayUri.get(position));

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Ohh and before someone tells me that there are other same questions with my own , i know . i tried all of them and i couldnt get things to work on my own situation.

I know that i want to get the uri from a selected image so i can pass it to another activity i created which makes it fullscreen. I just dont know how to get it

This is what i have tried. But how can i get the uri of the clicked image ?

```
final Uri[] uri = {new Uri};
    gvGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int Uri,long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            uri[0] = (android.net.Uri) GalleryAdapter.getUri();
            Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FullScreenActivity.class);
            intent.setData(uri[0]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and inside the gallery adapter

```
  public Object getUri() 
    {
        return mArrayUri;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you couldn't get working.

Comment: I'm not sure what `GalleryAdapter.getUri()` is, but if you have the `Uri` array available in `onItemClick()`, you can get the corresponding `Uri` from that. The third parameter in `onItemClick()` is the position, which you've named `Uri`, in this case. Use that as the array index; i.e., `intent.setData(uri[Uri]);`. You might want to rename that parameter to `position`, so it doesn't cause any confusion.

Comment: wait . you lost me there . The Array which contains the uris from ALL the images in the gridview is ImagePaths. A way i though which could work is trying to get which image # the user is clicking, and getting that number from the ImagePaths to the new intent . For example the user is clicking image number 4 , which is the 3rd cell of the ImagePaths array so it sends the 3rd Uri to the FullScreenActivity

Comment: "The Array which contains the uris from ALL the images in the gridview is ImagePaths." – Then substitute `ImagePaths.get(Uri)` for `uri[Uri]` in my example. I just used `uri` because that's what you've got there. And, as I suggested too, you should rename that `int Uri` parameter to `int position`. So then, `intent.setData(ImagePaths.get(position));`. Btw, `ImagePaths` is an `ArrayList`, not an array.

Comment: Great that worked like charm . And if sometime i want to add a swiping function will it be easy to implement to my current code ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by swiping, exactly, but these days, `RecyclerView` is probably easier to modify for stuff like that. You could likely find an existing solution out there for whatever it is you'd like to add.

Comment: full screen swiping like the one on every stock android gallery . where you go through all images by swiping left and right while still at foul screen

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how you mean to integrate that with your `GridView`, but the original "official" component that does that is [`ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager). There are also helper classes now available that make `RecyclerView` act like a `ViewPager`, in case that might be more appropriate for your case.